# How do we know when an image is fully loaded in an ImageSurface

Tags: famo.us

This question was posted on the IRC channel.

> You want to be able to know when an image is fully loaded in an ImageSurface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there was a complete load by checking if the image load is `complete` on deploy. The following code example listens for the DOM event on the image element (`ImageSurface`). On deploy, check to see if the image is already complete on the `ImageSurface`. If not, then we listen for the image to load.

**[Example Here:](http://jsbin.com/fuyuhe/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

  var image = new ImageSurface({
    size: [200, 200]
  });

  var surface = new Surface({});

  image.on('deploy',function(){ 
    console.log('deployed image', this);
    if (this._currentTarget.complete) {
      surface.setContent('Fully loaded on deploy');
    } else {
      this.on('load', function(e){
        surface.setContent('completed loading = ' + this._currentTarget.complete);
      });
    }
  });

  image.setContent("http://code.famo.us/assets/famous.jpg");

  mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    align: [0.5, 0.5],
    origin: [0.5, 0.5]
  })).add(image);

  mainContext.add(surface);
```